# AWS API Gateway Security with a Custom Authoriser & AWS Service Integrations

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

When using API Gateway to proxy AWS services such as S3 works great.

However it would seem that security is an afterthought. The execution role that is used for AWS Service integration seems to leave open the integrated service when using a customer authorizer.

The Custom Authorizer in API Gateway returns a `principalId` (e.g. a userId) and an IAM policy document. How could one build an IAM policy for the execution role of the service integration which would require for example the userId/principalId to be in the path of an S3 object.

I.e. using a custom authorizer + S3 integration how do you secure object access to only a particular key space where the principalId is part of an object tag or path? 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/policy-keys-cwe.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Here is how I solved it with the path.

Assume user1 need to access their data and their space is

```
domain/user1/object1
domain/user1/object2
```

In the custom Authorizer you can return policy that the user can access only  domain/user1/*. You can use any **pattern** you want and organize the storage to whatever namespace you want. If you want to expand namespace for multiple users you can do access to

```
domain/user1/*
domain/managers/*
```

And APIGateway will take care of the rest. If the user tries to access anything other than the above URL paths, the user will get 403 forbidden.

Followed the documentation from AWS and works perfectly,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html

In Addition, if you want authentication I would recommend CloudFront signed URL and Cognito.